# Matlab GUI/GUIDE Appending item to vector stored in in a handle

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm working on a program that records user button-presses in response to a sequence of tones. I am storing the timing of the button presses in a vector (pushTimes), which I am storing in GUIDE's "handles" structure, and I would like the new time of each button press to be appended to the pushTimes vector. However, handles doesn't seem to be storing the new vector with the appended value, leaving me with an empty vector after the button is pressed.

Edit: Because people were having difficulty reproducing the error, I'm posting the whole file The relevant code is in the callBack pushButton1. pushButton2 and pushButton3 are "pause" and "start" buttons, respectively. The error occurs even when I don't pause the program.

```
function varargout = simpleGui(varargin)
% SIMPLEGUI M-file for simpleGui.fig
%      SIMPLEGUI, by itself, creates a new SIMPLEGUI or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = SIMPLEGUI returns the handle to a new SIMPLEGUI or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      SIMPLEGUI('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in SIMPLEGUI.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      SIMPLEGUI('Property','Value',...) creates a new SIMPLEGUI or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before simpleGui_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to simpleGui_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help simpleGui

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 27-May-2014 11:00:12

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @simpleGui_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @simpleGui_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before simpleGui is made visible.
function simpleGui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to simpleGui (see VARARGIN)
[soundVec, codeVec] = FourToneDifDirection();
handles.soundVec = soundVec;
handles.codeVec = codeVec;
handles.toneTimes = zeros(1,length(soundVec));
handles.pushTimes = [];
handles.toneNum = 1;
% Choose default command line output for simpleGui
handles.output = hObject;
% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);


% UIWAIT makes simpleGui wait for user response (see UIRESUME)




% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = simpleGui_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function handles = pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
dv = datevec(now);
%get the seconds from datevec
sec = dv(6);
%append to the pushTimes vector
handles.pushTimes = [handles.pushTimes sec]
%debugging line, should return a large vector after button is pressed multiple times     but only returns a single value.
handles.pushTimes
guidata(hObject, handles)

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
UIresume
guidata(hObject, handles);
soundVec = handles.soundVec
n = 1;
while(n<length(soundVec))
    guidata(hObject, handles);
    n = handles.toneNum
    midigen(handles.soundVec(n), 0.25);
    dv = datevec(now);
    sec = dv(6);
    handles.toneTimes(n) = sec;
    n = n+1;
    handles.toneNum = n;
end
guidata(hObject, handles)



% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
guidata(hObject, handles);
codeVec = handles.codeVec;
toneTimes = handles.toneTimes;
pushTimes = handles.pushTimes
calculateHitRate(codeVec, toneTimes, pushTimes,1,handles.toneNum);
guidata(hObject, handles)
uiwait(handles.figure1);

function out = isWithin(x, low, high)
   out = x > low & x < high;


function [d1hr, d2hr, d3hr, d4hr] = calculateHitRate(codeVec, toneTimes, pushTimes, start, finish)
    d1Ct = sum(codeVec(start:finish) == 9);
    d2Ct = sum(codeVec(start:finish) == 10);
    d3Ct = sum(codeVec(start:finish) == 11);
    d4Ct = sum(codeVec(start:finish) == 12);
    d1Push = 0;
    d2Push = 0;
    d3Push = 0;
    d4Push = 0;
    for i = 1:length(pushTimes)
        pushTime = pushTimes(i)
        stimTime = pushTime - 2;
        for j = start:finish
            %if the stimulus was within 1.5 seconds before the push
            if codeVec(j) == 9 && isWithin(toneTimes(j), stimTime, pushTime)
                d1Push = d1Push+1;
            elseif codeVec(j) == 10 && isWithin(toneTimes(j), stimTime, pushTime)
                d2Push = d2Push+1;
            elseif codeVec(j) == 10 && isWithin(toneTimes(j), stimTime, pushTime)
                d3Push = d3Push+1;
            elseif codeVec(j) == 10 && isWithin(toneTimes(j), stimTime, pushTime)
                d4Push = d4Push+1;
            end
        end
    end
    d1hr = d1Push/d1Ct
    d2hr = d2Push/d2Ct
    d3hr = d3Push/d3Ct
    d4hr = d4Push/d4Ct
```

Comment: I tried your code and seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Edit: added the whole file.

Comment: I just added a line to demonstrate the problem in the pushbutton1_Callback function. handles.pushTimes should return a vector of values when the button is pressed multiple times, but it only returns the most recent value.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that if I paused the UI using pushButton2 and then started clicking pushButton1, the button would work as expected, i.e. it would append the newest button click time to a list. I think that there is some issue involving synchronization with the Matlab append function that causes strange behavior when doing something else at the same time (in this case, playing tones). I switched from using Matlab's vectors to java.util.Vector, and used the add() function, and now I can append to the Vector just fine.

Comment: I think it could be the pausing as MATLAB GUI is known to be not-so-reliable in such conditions. One more situation where I have seen undefined behaviour with MATLAB GUIs is when debugging using commands like `keyboard`. Not sure if I can offer any other tips/help on this issue.